# Why doesn't Elixir have a Math module?

Tags: elixir

I was wondering why Elixir doesn't have a Math module.

I understand that we can write this using Erlang `math:` module:

```
alias :math, as: Math
```

but, is it good practice to put that line in our Elixir code?

In **iex** it seems to work:

```
iex(1)> alias :math, as: Math
nil
iex(2)> Math.pi()
3.141592653589793
iex(3)> Math.pow(3, 2)
9.0
```

Alas, it is clear that we cannot get access to documentation in an Elixir way:

```
iex(4)> h(Math)
:math is an Erlang module and, as such, it does not have Elixir-style docs
```

Comment: Why should we duplicate existing Erlang functionality that's tested and proven?  Where is a compelling advantage to doing so?

Comment: Once I read @josevalim answer that duplicating module make no sense. Elixir in terms of Erlang, can use everything from Erlang, so if you doesn't change anything there's no point to clone these modules just like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually their are plenty of modules currently in erlang that are not present in elixir. Importing all of them would not make much sense, since corresponding erlang modules are available and its quite easy to use them in elixir too.

Also from the [docs](http://elixir-lang.org/blog/2013/08/08/elixir-design-goals/)

> Elixir runs in the same virtual machine and is compatible with OTP. Not only that, all the tools and libraries available in the Erlang ecosystem are also available in Elixir, simply because there is no conversion cost from calling Erlang from Elixir and vice-versa.

As for the documentation Elixir is still relatively new, people are [working on it](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3589). You should have the erlang docs in iex soon. https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3589

Answer (score 9):

> but, is it good practice to put that line in our Elixir code?

Yes. In the end, everything is translated into Erlang AST, then compiled into BEAM bytecode. We can't neither deny nor forget the heritage of Erlang in Elixir.

Comment: I would say 'no' since it is perfectly fine to call the erlang module directly and. Plus by not putting the line, you do not obfuscate that you are using an erlang module, since you probably don't want that abstraction anyway.

Comment: Is not sane for a language to depend on another lang. Where is the sovereignty there? If I would like to add a new math function, why do I need to ask another language (Erlang) to have it on Elixir. Elixir could have a Math module implementing / bypassing :erlang base function, and add extra functions over without depending on nobody...